# No biber executable but tlmgr claims it's installed

Tags: texlive, biber, installing, tlmgr

I am currently setting up a hosted VM to build my own little personal cloud. The VM is running ubuntu server 20.04 on an aarch64 platform. I would like to synchronize my .tex files with it and have them build there. To this end I installed Tex Live 2022 as described in the debian set up page https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html .

I ran in to some problems downloading from the repo that first got selected (mirrors.concertpass.com) when installing. The only package reported missing was `skills`, with a rather generic "downloading did not succeed (download_file failed)" error message. I have switched mirrors after the installation with `sudo tlmgr option repository ctan` and installed the package with tlmgr manually and as reported by tlmgr successfully.

I ran a check afterwards which reported no problems:

```
ubuntu@cloud:~$ sudo tlmgr check all
Running check files:
Running check depends:
Running check executes:
Running check runfiles:
Running check texmfdbs
```

Biber however seems not to be installed.

```
ubuntu@cloud:~$ sudo biber

Command 'biber' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install biber
```

Indeed biber is not in the `texlive/2022/bin/aarch64-linux` directory, but according tlmgr is installed, with a missing dependency.

```
ubuntu@cloud:~$ sudo tlmgr info biber
package:     biber
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A BibTeX replacement for users of BibLaTeX
longdesc:    Biber is a...
installed:   Yes
revision:    61867
tlmgr: cannot find depending package biber.aarch64-linux
tlmgr: action info returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Manually installing biber.aarch64-linux does not seem to be possible:

```
ubuntu@cloud:~$ sudo tlmgr install biber.aarch64-linux
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package biber.aarch64-linux not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

How can I make my system provide a biber installation that is integrated into the tlmgr eco-system (particularly latexmk)?

Comment: texlive 2022 biber is not yet available on that plaform: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2022-April/047999.html

Comment: Oh, well that's unfortunate. I'm not going to be able to build it myself I dont think. What are the risks of installing it from apt? And thank you for the lightning fast reply.

Comment: If you install Biber from `apt` (if it is available at all) that version is unlikely to match with the `biblatex` version you have installed via your vanilla TeX Live. The `apt` version is going to match to the `biblatex` version provided by the TeX Live installable via `apt`.

Comment: biber in my Texlive 2022 is 2.17 same as texlive 2021 so if it was in texlive 2021 aarch64 you could copy a binary across I think

Comment: That makes sense, I can see that in the ubuntu repository for 22.04 the biber package is version 2.17, the newest one. I intend to upgrade ubuntu for other reasons already, so I will try that once it gets released or hopefully someone builds biber for my platform.